# Is the Raspberry Pi 3 powerful enough for real time image processing?

Tags: pi-3, python

I was curious as to if anyone has used the RPi3 for real-time image processing? If so, was there any computational delay while doing it real-time?

I am planning to use an external GPU to train a CNN that can classify weeds and crops. I want to make sure the RPi3 can handle image processing features like segmentation and be able to classify the weed and crops in real-time using pixel-wise classification(might require a CNN).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on several factors:

- Required accuracy of the classifier
- Size of the input images
- Number of image classes
- Real-time requirements (how much time can the classifier take to do the job)

Given that, I managed to run a very simple classifier based on TensorFlow and a custom MobileNet model retrained in order to recognize two classes of images: apples from kiwis, given images of 160x120 pixels; you can see a demo in this video to get an idea:

[Apple or Kiwi?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DBpHXfxHucE&t=2s)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the size of each image and the structure of the CNN itself.
However, I think that the RPi isn't powerful enough to get decent results in reasonable time.